# Comparing an array of np string when function is compiled using numba

Tags: numpy, numba

what is the best way to compare a numpy array consisting of strings when the function is compiled using numba

```
test_array=np.array(['1','2','3','4','5'])

@jit(nopython=True) 
def numba_optimised(check):

    return (check=='1')

numba_optimised(test_array)
```

The code segment below only returns a singular value, which is undesirable. What is the best way to resolve this?

Comment: Why do you want to use numba for that? Just use pure numpy broadcasting.

Comment: This is just an example as I am unable to post the full source code here but essentially I am trying to speed up some calculations that I am working on. based on my past knowledge, I know numba and string don't always play well, but I am wondering whether things have changed since then.

Comment: Optimization problems without a clear example are tricky to answer. For instance, a loop might be fine if the rest of the computation is the bottleneck. You should post a minimal example that is the closest to your real use case.

Comment: Will try to provide the example when I can :). But just to summarise things a bit in case I don't have time to come back is that in my original numpy loop, there is a point of time where I need to evaluate a numpy array consisting of string with a single string. I was just wondering whether is there a way to do the whole thing within a numba compiled function instead of breaking the function in between.

Comment: Create an empty boolean array, use a loop for the comparison and return the array. This will not be slower than the vectorized solution because Numba compile the code (and the code is not SIMD friendly anyway though it could in specific cases like this). For big arrays or ones holding a big string, Numba will not be faster, it will actually be slower. For short ones Numba may help to reduce the start-up overhead. If you have strings of size 1, then comparing string is very inefficient and you should compare integers. I guess the example is certainly not representative.